# Communication between Wopi served Iframe embedded excel-online document and parent window

Tags: ms-wopi

I have an excel-online embedded document on an Iframe element. The file is served by a WOPI host to client.

I want to be able have the Iframe communicate with the parent window the same way that an oline file served from OneDrive can communicate with its parent window using the Excel Services JavaScript API (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh315812(v=office.14).aspx). I want to be able to read elements such as a cell that is in focus etc.

Wopi protocol suggest using HTML PostMessage which has limitation as it does not allow for manipulation of the embedded file the same way Excel Services JavaScript API does.

Is there a way to achieve this with an Iframe embedded excel-oline file served through a WOPI host?

Comment: I too use the OneDrive Excel Services JavaScript API extensively.  However, it stopped working for me last night (you?). I have also been searching for an alternative for a long time (due to reliability issues).  I am not aware of another way to use an API to control publicly embedded Excel Online (get/set values, get events, etc.). The embed configurator in Office 365 (OneDrive for Business and SharePoint) does not allow embedding with the JavaScript API like the free OneDrive Consumer.  How do you access the WOPI host?

Comment: Wopi defines a set of [REST endpoints](http://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/) and operations that can be excecuted by issuing HTTP requests to those endpoint.

Comment: Hi, did you find the way to solve this?